# Ajax not posting to php

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, database

```
$(".eventer button[name=lol]").click(function() {
num = $(this).parent().data('num');
if(typeof num != 'number'){
    num = 0;
}
$(this).attr('disabled', true); // don't allow a second click until previous action has completed

$(this).parent().data('num', ++num);
$.ajax('javas.php', {   success: function(response) { 
$(this).parent().next('.status').html(num);
$(this).attr('disabled', false); // reset
})
});
```

If i comment the ajax part out everything works fine but i need to post the variable num to php so i can store it in a database

Comment: You should add data to ajax call, like $.ajax('javas.php', {  data: {'num': ++num}, success: ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try indenting your code for readability:

```
$.ajax('javas.php', {   
    success: function(response) { 
        $(this).parent().next('.status').html(num);
        $(this).attr('disabled', false); // reset
    }
   ) // <-- ??
});
```

Then you'll see there is an error.

If you look at the jQuery website http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

And translate it to yours:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'javas.php',
  success: function(data) {
        $(this).parent().next('.status').html(num);
        $(this).attr('disabled', false); // reset
  }
});
```

This should work.

You will still need to add your data to the request though:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'javas.php',
  data: "num="+num+"&id="+id,
  success: function(data) {
        $(this).parent().next('.status').html(num);
        $(this).attr('disabled', false); // reset
  }
});
```

Comment: nothing happens when i click the buttons, they become disabled

Comment: Yes, because the AJAX call doesn't return a positive result. This will only work on your server where javas.php exists and returns a value.

Comment: not even working then, maybe theres something wrong with javas.php

<?php 

  $lol =  $_POST['num'];
  
  echo " $lol";
  

?>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5954/discussion-between-richard-and-foshoeiyyy)

Comment: I really need to change $.ajax to $.post

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
$.ajax( {
  url : 'javas.php',
  type: 'post',
 success: function() { }
});
```

Edit:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
url:'javas.php',
type:'post',
data:{num:num},
success:function(response){
 $(this).parent().next('.status').html(num);
    $(this).attr('disabled', false); // reset
},
error:function(){}
});
```

and on the php side get the data as

```
$var = $_POST["num"];
```